# How would I create a PDF in salesforce on any object WITHOUT using ANY code

Tags: visualforce, pdf, getcontentaspdf

Business case - So I have to create invoices (not quotes) in PDF format from opportunities that contain a whole lot of account and opportunity object fields.

I dont want to use VF or in-fact any coding at all.
Possible?

---

Yes its possible. I will give the solution away soon. But first, let me know if you have any ideas?

20/1/16
Half Solution - Checkout my post at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/generate-pdfs-salesforce-without-writing-any-code-harleen-mann

Following question: How do we create PDFs on a totally unrelated custom object?

Comment: If not using AppExchange - this is nice. Waiting for it.

Comment: this isn't from appexchange :) Its an Admin's trick

Comment: you are throwing a challenge :). So you hacked the url.

Comment: Addition - The PDF generation will be for all objects eventually. 
My POC is on opportunities though. But it will work on all objects!

Comment: @Mann do you want to genarate all object detail page in PDF?

Comment: @Tushar, no the generate PDF button can be made available on all objects - is what i meant.

Comment: @Mann yes add the button but what action do you want to perform? Print the detail page. Like on account page if i click on button it will print the detail page of account.

Comment: @Mann I think you can give ans to this question.

Comment: @Ratan I'll give a partial answer and lead another question

Comment: @Mann i think Tushar gave you correct Ans... Why don't you mark his ans as best

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a salesforce native functionality. Just add Create PDF button in Invoice Layout.

[image: Button on UI]
[image: PDF native]

Added Images for your reference.

As you don't mention previously that you want to use it for all object then i think it is URL Hack.

```
https://ap1.salesforce.com/quote/quoteTemplateDataViewer.apexp?id=0Q090000000eeUa&headerHeight=10&footerHeight=10&summlid=0EH90000000uhOY#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&zoom=90
```

This is a base URL SF use for Quote generation.

Comment: interesting - what do you mean by that Tushar?

Comment: go to setup, enable Quotes, and there -- you can generate Quote for opportunity and save that as PDF

Comment: Aaahh.. I see. I am actually talking to generating any PDFs - not just quotes and invoices

Comment: @Mann you mean generally for all objects?

Comment: Yes generally for all objects eventually. My POC is on opportunities though. But it will work on all objects!

Comment: Yes tushar you have mostly nailed it :)

Answer (score 2):

Its salesforce native functionality if you are familiar with salesforce CRM than whenever you create an invoice or quote under an opportunity than their is a button called create PDF to genrate invoices without any code